# Showing that the set of odd permutations is not a subgroup of Sn

Tags: permutations

I want to show that the set of odd permutations is not a subgroup of Sn.
Let the set $H= \{\text{odd permutations}\}$.

Is it enough to say that the Identity permutation which sends all of its elements on themselves is even therefore, $e \notin H$ therefore $H$ is not a subgroup of $S_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's enough. You can also say that the product of any two odd permutations is even, and therefore not an element of $H$. This shows that $H$ isn't closed (as long as $H$ has at least one element in it). Either argument works just fine as a proof.

Comment: I have never seen the terminology pair/impair and I would therefore be close to calling it wrong rather than unusual. Uneven as well actually.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Well, you're not wrong. I just felt lenient today.